# loop only appends on last button

Tags: python, for-loop, append

I've made a gui with a variable amount of buttons and entries, dependent on earlier user inputs. I want to store the new entries in a list. My loop however will only append the last entry created in the loop. How can I get each button to append it's respective user entry?

```
def getFuseType():
          (Fuse.fuseType).append(e.get()
          print(Fuse.fuseType)
for i in range(1,int(Site.NoFuses)+1):
        l = Label(FuseWindow, text = "Fuse Type")
        e = Entry(FuseWindow)
        l.grid(row = 1, column = i+3)
        e.grid(row = 2, column = i+3)          
        b = Button(FuseWindow, text = "ok", command = getFuseType)        
        b.grid(row = 3, column = i+3)
```

[Fuse GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5mDn.png)
see the image I've uploaded, The top right 'OK' button appends the entry. I want the top Left button to also append it's respective entry.

Comment: Why did you define `getFuseType` inside your `for` loop??

Comment: Actually not sure. I just took it out of the loop though and nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function isn't creating a closure around the `e` variable so they only affect the most recent (last) object assigned to `e`. If you really want to do this you'll need to use a defaulted arg..

```
for i in range(1,int(Site.NoFuses)+1):
        l = Label(FuseWindow, text = "Fuse Type")
        e = Entry(FuseWindow)
        l.grid(row = 1, column = i+3)
        e.grid(row = 2, column = i+3)
        def getFuseType(e=e):
            (Fuse.fuseType).append(e.get())
            print(Fuse.fuseType)

        b = Button(FuseWindow, text = "ok", command = getFuseType)        
        b.grid(row = 3, column = i+3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get `getFuseType` out of the `for`, it is defined every loop iteration and hence you only get the last create entry `e`

```
def getFuseType(ent):
    Fuse.fuseType.append(ent)
    print(Fuse.fuseType)

for i in range(1,int(Site.NoFuses)+1):
        l = Label(FuseWindow, text = "Fuse Type")
        e = Entry(FuseWindow)
        ent = e.get()
        l.grid(row = 1, column = i+3)
        e.grid(row = 2, column = i+3)    
        b = Button(FuseWindow, text = "ok", command = lambda ent = ent:getFuseType(ent))        
        b.grid(row = 3, column = i+3)
```